# How do I set a default configuration for GridView in Yii2 without the widget factory?

Tags: php, yii2

This is what a gridview looks like in Yii2:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ...
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I want change my grids a little bit, so I add this line:

```
tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table table-condensed'],
```

This works great, but...

#### **I want this to be the default value for all my grids!**

In Yii 1, this would look like this:

```
'widgetFactory' => array(
    'widgets' => array(
        'CGridView' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => ['class'=>'table table-condensed']
        ),
    ),
),
```

In Yii2 however there is no widget factory. Instead, looking at the main config, I would expect this to work:

```
'grid'=>[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
    'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table table-condensed'],
],
```

But it does not. So what am I doing wrong? Any hints much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Yii::$container->set().

For example:

```
// add following line in config/web.php and config/console.php
require __DIR__ . '/container.php';

// creates a config/container.php file and add following
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\GridView', [
    'tableOptions' => [
        'class' => 'table table-condensed',
    ],
]);
```

For more information: [Dependency Injection Container](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html) and [Practical Usage](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#practical-usage)

and Yii::$objectConfig has been removed in Yii 2.0.0-beta.

For example (Since version 2.0.11):

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    // ...
    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            yii\grid\GridView::class => [
                'tableOptions' => [
                    'class' => 'table table-condensed',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

For more information: [Application Configurations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#application-configurations)

Comment: Showing as unknown property container

Answer (score 4):

### Edit: This answer is no longer applicable since Yii 2.0.0-beta.

```
Yii::$objectConfig = [
    'yii\grid\GridView' => [
        'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table table-condensed']
    ],
];
```

Comment: I was also looking for this solutions. where exactly you need to put this code?

Comment: As jamband points out, this has been changed. I've also now marked his answer as the correct one.